# belongs_to has_many assosiation help

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a joined table for the models category and products (both created with scaffold). The Product model is this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category 

  def category_id
    category.id if category
  end

  def category_id=(id)
    self.category = Category.find_by_id(id) unless id.blank?
  end
end
```

and the category model is this:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end
```

In the form.html.erb I create a dropbox with all the classes for the user to choose from:

```
<p>
      <label for="product_category_id">Category:</label><br />
      <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.find(:all), :id, :name, :prompt => "Select a Category" %>
</p>
```

Yet when I take a look at the show of the product:

```
<p>
  <b>Category:</b>
  <%= @product.category_id %>
</p>
```

or the list of the products (index.html.erb):

```
<td><%= product.category_id %></td>
```

There's no category. Just blank. I don't get it. Is something wrong with the category_id method or the association?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need the explicit `category_id` and `category_id=` methods. `ActiveRecord` will handle those for you  for a `belongs_to` association.

Secondly, there seems to be a mismatch between whether you want a `has_and_belongs_to_many` or a `has_many`/`belongs_to` association. If you have a join table then you have the former, in which case both sides of the association should be declared with `has_and_belongs_to_many`. If you are just using a `category_id` on the products table then the other end of your association on Category should be `has_many :products`.

With a join model:

```
class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :product
end
```

you would define in your `Product` class:

```
has_many :categorizations
has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations
```

Then, because your association is a 'many' association, you do not get a `.category` method on a product. You do however get a `categories` method (plus several more methods - look at the has_many documentation). If you name your `collection_select` `category_ids` then it should work as expected. You may also want to add the 'multiple' option to the select in order to choose more than one category.

Comment: I tried using a join model ( categorization model ) with product_id, category_id attributes. Categorization belongs_to category and product. And Product use through => categorization. I removed category_id method but when I do, I get error message "undefined method `category_id' for #<Product:0x1043fa110>" after I remove the category_id (or both) and "undefined local variable or method `category' for #<Product:0x10415bfa8>" after I remove category_id=. What seems to be the problem? Thank you for your response and your time beforehand.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include details of using a join table. The main issue from your comment is that you are trying to refer to a single category when the association you want is for many categories.

Answer (score 0):

Your association is obviously incorrect. As pointed out, the category has_many products. And in case you want to use a many-to-many relationship you're strongly advised to use the has_many :through relationship.